# How to determine whether contours are within X and Y values

Tags: python, opencv

I have the centroid of my screen, which I do +75 and -75. Within these values I would like to detect contours. However I end up with the following error:

```
    (xg, yg, wg, hg) = cv.boundingRect(cntArea)
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.5.5) /tmp/pip-wheel-efxaz4j7/opencv-python_bedc0fac27944da0921e079da44d32bf/opencv/modules/imgproc/src/shapedescr.cpp:874: 
error: (-215:Assertion failed) npoints >= 0 && (depth == CV_32F || depth == CV_32S) in function 'pointSetBoundingRect'
```

I know what the error means, but I simply cannot grasp as to why this is happening. When I do the following, it works and returns the biggest contour, but not within the range of `centroid + 75 and centroid - 75`

```
cntArea = max(cnts, key=cv.contourArea)
```

So what I am trying to do is: Loop through the contours and if it's a rectangle within X and Y values it should add it to a list (which I later on convert to numpy array).

My code looks like this:

```
def detectObject(self, lower, upper, topVal = False, botVal = False):
    # Threshold the HSV image to get only blue colors
    mask = cv.inRange(self.hsv, lower, upper)
    cnts = self.findContours(mask)
    filtercnts = []
    cntArea = None
    #contours were found
    if (len(cnts) > 0):
        ##topval is min, botval is pos
        if (botVal is not False and topVal is not False):
            for cnt in cnts:
                if (self.is_bad_contour(cnt) == False):
                    cntArea = cv.contourArea(cnt)
                    ##this is where it goes wrong
                    (xg, yg, wg, hg) = cv.boundingRect(cntArea)
                    if (yg > topVal and yg < botVal):
                         filtercnts.append(cntArea)
            
            if (len(filtercnts) > 0):
                np_arr = np.array(filtercnts)
                cntArea = max(np_arr)
        else:
            cntArea = max(cnts, key=cv.contourArea)

    # return the biggest contourArea
    return cntArea
```

How I call the function:

```
area = self.detectObject(self.lower_blue, self.upper_blue, int(self.screenHeight / 2 - 75), int(self.screenHeight / 2 + 75))
```

how my `findContours` looks like:

```
def findContours(self, mask):
    return cv.findContours(mask.copy(), cv.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)[-2]
```

Comment: What colour is?

Comment: @toyotaSupra Yes. The colour I filter on is blue.

Comment: So are you trying to drawn on virtual screen?

Comment: @toyotaSupra Yes. I am trying to draw on the frame yes.

Comment: But you can do this def detectObject(self, lower, upper, topVal = False, botVal = False):

Comment: @toyotaSupra Yes I can. However when I set topVal and botVal it crashes